# Retrieve Klout score using Email Address

Tags: facebook, email, klout

I'm trying to find a way to lookup a Klout score using either an email address or a facebookID. Looking at the API documentation for Klout (http://developer.klout.com/io-docs) it looks like it's possible to do this with just about everything else except facebook or email.

Am I missing something? I would have expected getting a klout score from an email address would be fairly standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't offer FacebookID because Facebook's TOS doesn't allow two 3rd party developers to transfer Facebook IDs between eachother.
We don't offer email addresses to respect user's privacy, and it would only apply to a registered userbase.

There are outside companies that provide email to social identifier translation, which may enable you to get at this data, but it's not something we're looking to provide directly in the near future.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on the companies that provide "email to social identifier translation"? Thanks.